# getting values in column from inside the function outer

Tags: r

I am attempting to get the values of the row being passed into `outer`. What am I missing?

```
#create dataframe as example that will work for this function
exampledf<- matrix(ceiling(runif(16,0,50)), ncol=4)
colnames(exampledf)<-c("col1","col2","col3","col4")
x<-as.data.frame(exampledf)
cols<-cbind(colnames(x))
#end creating variables

  matr<-outer(cols,cols,function(a,b){
    return(eval(parse(text = "x$a")))#Doesnt work
    })
```

My end goal is to get a partial correlation matrix. The function spcor.test() takes in two vectors (not the dataframe I am trying to give it). I am trying to write a version that takes a dataframe.

All my code so far:

```
library(matrixcalc)
library(ppcor)
exampledf<- matrix(ceiling(runif(16,0,50)), ncol=4)
while(is.singular.matrix(exampledf)!=TRUE){
  exampledf<- matrix(ceiling(runif(16,0,50)), ncol=4)
}
colnames(exampledf)<-c("col1","col2","col3","col4")

#single example
#spcor.test(exampledf[,1],exampledf[,2],exampledf[,3])

x<-as.data.frame(exampledf)
cont<-"col3"
#semiCorr<-function(x,cont){ #x=dataframe to correlate, z=names of variables to control for
  library(ppcor)
  cols<-cbind(colnames(x))
  cols<-cols[-c(grep(cont,cols))]
  matr<-outer(cols,cols,function(a,b){
    get(x$a)
    #spcor.test(eval(parse(text = "x$a")),eval(parse(text = "x$b")),x[,c(cont)])
    })
  return((matr)) #return a matrix of the semipartial correlations
#}
#semiCorr(exampledf,"col3")

  cols<-cols[-c(grep(cont,cols))]
  matr<-outer(cols,cols,function(a,b){
    return(a)
    #return(eval(parse(text = "x$a")))#Doesnt work
  })
```

Comment: If it is to get the combinations, why don't you use `expand.grid`

Comment: @akrun, That looks interesting, but it doesnt seem like quite what I need. If I have 4 columns: col1, col2, col3, col4, I need to feed col1 and col2 into a function. Then col1 and col3 etc for all combinations. I may have misunderstood the function however.

Comment: To me precise `apply(expand.grid(cols, cols), 1, FUN= function(cols) x[cols])`

Comment: That worked great, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `expand.grid` with `apply`

```
apply(expand.grid(cols, cols), 1, FUN= function(cols) x[cols])
```